# How to get orders that have multiple rows with different statuses?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table:

```
order_id | status | created_at | updated_at
100        1        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
100        2        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
100        3        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
101        1        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
101        2        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
101        3        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
101        4        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
102        1        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
102        2        2022-01-01   2022-01-01
```

What I want to know is how to obtain orders that have status 3, but do not have status 4 in their history. That is, based on the example I have in the table, I should only be able to get the order with ID of 100.

Right now I manage to get that result with the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-30 23:11:59' AND status = 3 AND order_id NOT IN (
    SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE status IN(4) GROUP BY order_id
);
```

However, that long-term query will have performance issues because the subquery will search through all the records. Does anyone know a way to do it better?

Comment: Is the date range relevant to the problem?  What if the "4" is not in that date range?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation provides on option:

```sql
SELECT order_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING SUM(status = 3) > 0 AND SUM(status = 4) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select o3.*
from orders o3
left join orders o4 on o4.order_id=o3.order_id and o4.status=4
where o3.created_at between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-30 23:11:59' and o3.status=3 and o4.order_id is null
```

This excludes orders that have any orders row with status 4; if you only want to exclude ones where created_at is in that range, add an `o4.created_at between ...` condition to the left join on clause.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like this

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-30 23:11:59' and status <> 4
```

This will select all data excluding the rows with `status =4`